# How can I read all child elements from firebase without authentication if these elements were added by authenticated users? in Android Studio

Tags: java, android, firebase-realtime-database

[image]

How can I read all child elements from firebase without authentication if these elements were added by authenticated users? in Android Studio

Comment: What do you mean by "read all child elements"?

Comment: Are you looking for https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/android/lists-of-data#listen_for_value_events? If that doesn't answer your question, can you please edit it (there's a link right under it) to show the [minimal code of what you already tried](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)?